# How to redirect HTACCESS changes to now allow subdirectory URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was successfully able to change my `.htaccess` file to change the url to my website files, removing the `access` folder.
SITEMAP

```
index.php
/access
    -dashboard.php
    -posts.php
    -account.php
```

Old URL : `mywebsite.com/access/dashboard.php`
New URL: `mywebsite.com/dashboard.php`
This is all working perfectly, the only issue is that, I can still access my files from the old url. I would like to redirect that url to the new one so that it is not used anymore. How can I do this? 
Here is my current `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/access/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ access/$1.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteBase /` line:

```sh
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+access/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

This will match `/access/<anything>` from *raw Apache request* and redirect to a URL without `/access`.

Comment: do I keep my old rules or overwrite them with your suggested?

Comment: You should keep your rewrite rule, that's why I mentioned *insert this rule*

Comment: gotcha, wow that worked perfectly. i know this isnt exactly the venue for this, but I have a couple things I'd like to do with my htaccess file for query strings. would you be up for helping out? I can compensate you for your time. id rather get professional help then try to figure it out for the next 12 hours

Comment: Actually I am not a webmaster by profession. I do this is just out of hobby. I suggest you to create a new question and post all your issues in one post and I with many other experts here will try to help you out as best as we can.

Comment: i appreciate that, and though this may not be your profession, i have no problem giving you something for the effort you've put in to develop your skills. its the least i can do, after all, every hour of time i save is basically earned money somewhere down the road

Comment: Please start by posting all issues in a new question, trust me you will get best possible help. For compensating time, I would humbly request you to contribute to some charity of your liking.